# IONIC bluetooth printing

Tags: ionic-framework, android-bluetooth

Anyone have experience about printing using bluetooth printer using IONIC framework
is that can directly print to printer or i must install aplication printer service
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I made this, give it a try. Works on most bluetooth receipt printers:
https://github.com/razmans/ionicBluetoothPrint